# What is the base class for byte array

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to know what is the base class for byte array (byte[]) in java. For   example for String it is java.lang.String.

Comment: byte is a primitive type no class.

Comment: `System.out.println(byte[].class);`

Comment: the base class of String is Object

Answer (score 5):

The answer is **byte[].class**.

Example:

```
byte[] receivedMessage = consumer.receiveBody(byte[].class, 15000); // in ms or 15 seconds
```